# Connecting to mongodb on ssl via istio ingress gateway

Tags: mongodb, gateway, istio

I have the following code in my istio ingress gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: staging
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "my.mongodb.com"
    port:
      number: 27018
      protocol: MONGO
      name: mongo

---      

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myname
  namespace: staging
spec:
  hosts:
    - "my.mongodb.com"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 27018
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-service
        port:
          number: 27018
```

When I don't inject the sidecar, I can connect to this mongodb using `my.mongodb.com:27018 --ssl`

However, when I have the sidecar, I get the following error:

```
$ mongo my.mongodb.com:27018 --ssl
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://my.mongodb.com:27018/test
2019-02-13T23:30:44.201+1100 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server proxy.provendb.com:27018, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Secure.Transport: handshake failure :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

What is the correct way to set up ssl enabled mongodb on istio ?

## edit

I tried this

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: staging
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "my.mongodb.com"
    port:
      number: 443
      protocol: TLS
      name: tls-mongo
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH  


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myvs
  namespace: staging
spec:
  hosts:
    - "my.mongodb.com"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-service
        port:
          number: 27018
          # name: proxy-port
```

I get host unreachable

```
2019-02-14T05:38:08.392+1100 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server my.mongodb.com:443, connection attempt failed: HostUnreachable: Connection was closed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 3):

Use TLS as the protocol, see [an example](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/ingress-sni-passthrough/#configure-an-ingress-gateway). Just replace HTTPS with TLS, and fix the ports and the hosts. Use port 443, and in the destination specify port 27018. Access it by `mongo my.mongodb.com:443 --ssl`.

Comment: You have to change the Virtual Service as well, as in the example.

Comment: I have a similar requirement, but i do not have ssl on Mongo. I need to fwd the tcp connection via istio to the db  deployed as stateful set. The problem I get is, when I call using the service name within the container the mongosh connects, but when using FQDN & connecting from outside the cluster gives me connection 
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to <ipredacted>:25010 closed
Any clue as to why?  I checked the istio-proxy logs 
the request reaches the proxy but logs as 0 bytes sent & received.